# held broken packages - depends on older version, but newer version to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, and I am attempting to install `libgpgme-dev`. Here is the command and output.

```
$ sudo apt install libgpgme-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgpgme-dev : Depends: libgpgme11 (= 1.10.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.10.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have the dependency `libgpgme11` installed, but the version is `1.10.0-1ubuntu2`, whereas my desired package requires `1.10.0-1ubuntu1`.

```
$ dpkg --list | grep libgpgme11
ii  libgpgme11:amd64  1.10.0-1ubuntu2  amd64  GPGME - GnuPG Made Easy (library)
```

**How can I install `libgpgme-dev` given my current state?**

I searched the installed reverse dependencies of `libgpgme11`, and this is what I find.

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed libgpgme11
libgpgme11
Reverse Depends:
  libgpgmepp6
  fwupd
  seahorse
  libvolume-key1
  libgpgmepp6
  fwupd
  libgmime-3.0-0
```

Here are the outputs of `apt-cache policy` for the relevant packages.

```
$ apt-cache policy libgpgme11 libgpgme-dev
libgpgme11:
  Installed: 1.10.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.10.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.10.0-1ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.10.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libgpgme-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.10.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.10.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: can you add `apt-cache policy libgpgme11 libgpgme-dev ` to your question please?

Comment: @nobody - i added the output. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall  libgpgme11=1.10.0-1ubuntu1` Then try again.

Comment: Did you remember to update the local catalog (`sudo apt update`) before attempting the install? If not (or not sure) please do so now and re-run `apt-cache policy libgpgme11 libgpgme-dev`

Comment: @steeldriver - yes I ran `sudo apt update` before all of this. Would installing `libgpgme11=1.10.0-1ubuntu1` potentially cause problems? This is a shared computer.

Comment: If you have concerns you cam make a simulation first.  `sudo apt -s install --reinstall  libgpgme11=1.10.0-1ubuntu1`

Comment: thanks @nobody - from that simulation, it seems like only `libgpgme11` will be modified. if you want to submit this as an answer, i'm happy to accept it

Comment: @jakub it kind of looks like you had the `bionic-updates` repository in your sources.list when you installed `libgpgme11` but now have only `bionic` ...

Comment: @steeldriver - interesting... it could be. would you suggest adding back `bionic-updates`?

Comment: @jakub I would expect that if you add back `bionic-updates` and re-run `sudo apt update` then you will see version `1.10.0-1ubuntu2` of both packages

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: Wow, nice catch @steeldriver. Indeed `bionic-updates` was not included, and now when I try to install my desired packages (in simulation), I don't get the hold errors. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)